# Drupal 7 taxonomy term fields not handling content filters

Tags: 7, views, theming, taxonomy-terms

**Image Resize Filter** doesn't work with taxonomy term description.
Resizing works fine in nodes and blocks, but not in views for taxonomy term.

I'm loading term in my view template. And render its description(also tried custom) field.

```
$term = taxonomy_term_load($term_id);
print render($term->description);
```

I've tried to render with field_get_items and field_view_field.

Then i've figured out that html **content filter doesn't work with taxonomy terms fields** either.

Does anyone know *how to apply content filters to taxonomy term fields*(include description)?

Drupal core 7.5/7.81

Thanks for the replies.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to use `check_markup` function.
So, in my case, it was `print check_markup($current->description, 'filtered_html');` to output textfield with content filters.